# same customize form for edit and create page symfony

Tags: forms, symfony

I have started to use symfony.

I am facing problem for create and edit form customization.

I have created a entity with crud. Now I want to customize 'create form' new.html.twig and I am doing with

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}

    {{ form_row(form.task) }}
    {{ form_row(form.dueDate) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

My question is for 'edit form': what should I do that I can use the same customized form without duplication?

thanks in advance..

Comment: hi @Jd patel, you can use [Symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-theming), to overwrite form default layout,I hope this will help you to customize your form layput.

Comment: if you're having a problem with rendering it e.g: you have removed a field from your create form in the edit form, then each time check if that field is defined e.g: {% if form.task is defined %} {{form_row(form.task)}} ...{% endif %}. if you're having a problem withh the backend then you have to use eventlisteners.see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#customizing-your-form-based-on-the-underlying-data

Answer (score 0):

You can set the form `action` dynamically using a couple of different methods.

First you could pass the action into the template as a variable that is different for each parent template like..

new.html.twig

```
{{ include('AcmeBundle:Form:_form.html.twig', 
    {'form': form, 'action': path('create_route') }) }}
```

edit.html.twig

```
{{ include('AcmeBundle:Form:_form.html.twig', 
    {'form': form, 'action': path('edit_route', {'id': form.vars.value.id }) }}
    // Or the actual object id if the object has been passed to the template
```

<kbd>_form.html.twig</kbd>

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action': action }) }}
```

Or you can check for the presence of an id in your present object and then set the action depending on that. This version does make the template a little less reusable as the action is hardcoded but that would only be an issue if you are planning on having the same form for multiple different pages.

<kbd>_form.html.twig</kbd>

```
{% set action = form.vars.value.id is null 
    ? path('create_route') 
    : path('edit_route', {'id': form.vars.value.id })
%}
{{ form_start(form, {'action': action }) }}
```

*Note: Strings have been split to multiple lines for readability.*